# "Неохотно" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

"Сознание возвращалось не()охотно" — сперва написала слитно, а потом засомневалась. Это законченное предложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы напрасно сомневаетесь. Как известно, существительные, прилагательные, наречия на -о пишутся с частицей НЕ слитно, если нет противопоставления и это слово можно заменить синонимом без НЕ. И одно, и другое условия здесь соблюдаются. Правда, Розенталь допускает раздельное написание по следующему правилу: НЕ пишется слитно при утверждении, а раздельно - при отрицании. Насколько я понимаю авторитетного ученого, речь идет о тех случаях, когда мы не можем с абсолютной уверенностью заменить слово с частицнй НЕ синонимом (по смыслу), то есть когда возникает ситуация "50 на 50". Мы отрицаем, что сознание возвращалось охотно, но не утверждаем, что оно возвращалось "с удовольствием, с радостью, с готовностью, с дорогой душой". Но думается, что это уж излишние тонкости. Нужен, конечно, весь контекст, но в том законченном предложении, которое Вы привели вполне оправдано слитное написание.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем смысл ваших сомнений? Если чисто орфографически, то все правильно, в нейтральном варианте написание слитное.
Вот если вас не удовлетворяет такое написание *по смыслу*, то можно разбираться. Но в данном случае я просто не могу предствавить даже фантастический контекст, при котором "не охотно" было бы отрицанием того, что сознание "возвращалось охотно" - и таким образом требовало бы раздельного написания. Если вы такой контекст знаете - и именно его хотите его передать такой фразой, - то можете писать раздельно.